Moving "portable" Chromium to another computer results in "Chrome detected that some of your settings were corrupted by another program"
I use Chromium builds (from here) in "portable" mode by launching it with chrome.exe --user-data-dir=user_a. It works.
chrome-win\
  |- Dictionaries\
  |- locales\
  |- ...
  |- user_a\     <- user data, profiles, browser history, logged sessions, ...
  |- ...
  |- chrome.exe

The problem is that when moving this folder to another computer, I can successfully start chrome.exe --user-data-dir=user_a, the different profiles are still there, the browsing history is still present, but some settings are lost, and the websites logged-in sessions are lost. How to prevent this from happening?

Chrome detected that some of your settings were corrupted by another program and reset them to their original defaults.


The question Understand structure of Chrome User Profile data to Transfer to new PC/ OS & avoid Settings corruption Error? is linked to this, but not to the portable usage, with --user-data-dir (=nothing saved in C:\, nothing in %APPDATA%, nothing in %LOCALAPPDATA%), thus not a duplicate.
Related, but not duplicate: https://portableapps.com/node/65174, How can I copy Chrome settings without them getting reset?, Storing session data and cookies of portable browsers in folder of these portable browsers - not working with Chrome

So are you using Google Chrome or Chromium in the end? These are 2 different browsers that shouldn't be randomly mixed in tags and question content. Regardless, none of those were ever fully portable anyways.

@Destroy666 Thank you for your message. I didn't mix Chrome/Chromium, let me be more precise: I use Chromium snapshots (see download link at the beginning of my post). When using this version, the .exe is named chrome.exe (and not chromium.exe). Also the dialog box shows Chrome detected that... , and not Chromium detected that ... but we have no control over this popup. None of those were ever fully portable anyways: they are very close to be. Also, the flag --user-data-dir makes it nearly possible to use it that way, so investigation is useful here.

Yes, Chromium's exe is called chrome.exe for historical reasons, but the app is still called Chromium not Chrome and there's 0 reason for Google Chrome in tags either. The only valid usage is quoting the dialog box, otherwise mixing it serves no purpose other than making the question basically unanswerable as both browsers have their own portability problems (Google Chrome more of them than Chromium).

Oh ok I understand @Destroy666, I just removed the google-chrome tag. Is the clarification enough (if so, the close vote could be removed) or should I emphasize the clarification more in the question in your opinion? Thanks.

I edited it to a much more reasonable state. Remember the browser is not meant to be portable and you likely won't get answers. Trying a portable version from a website with portable versions is much more likely to result in success, although the problem with those is that they usuallty stop getting updated at some point.

In the Chromium bug tracker:

Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
There is no flag to remove this. You'll have to build your own version of Chromium if you want this. The storage system uses device bound encryption and that is why it is determining it is corrupted


Is the  issue on the bug tracker public? If so, it would be cool to add the link to the answer :-)
